# How to cleanly implement concurrency proof transactions within the model using callbacks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, transactions

Lets say a `Transfer` moves money from an account to another. This should only be possible if the source account has enough balance.

Given that we are dealing with money, we have to be careful about concurrency. I'm using Postgresql.

The solution should ideally:

1. Cleanly rollback and add a validation error in case of insufficient balance.
2. Be concurrency proof.

After some thought, I think the proper place to implement this business logic would be inside the `Transfer` model. Here's my first try:

```
def Transfer < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :check_account_balance

  def check_account_balance
    if from_account.balance < amount
      errors.add(:from_account, "Insufficient balance")
    end
  end

  before_create :update_balances
  def update_balances
    from_account.increment!(:balance, -1*amount)
    to_account.increment!(:balance, amount)
  end
end
```

We make use of the fact that ActiveRecord runs validations and callbacks within a single transaction.

I'm worried for the following concurrent scenario: Two parallel requests pass the `check_account_balance` and proceed to update the balances. If the account's balance is 1 and the amounts of both transfers are 1, then will this allow for both to go through? How do we fix this? Does this require locking on the account?

Also, how clean is the design of the code and would you do it in a different way?

Comment: Approach (1) is totally wrong. If you're not concurrency-safe, your attempt to reverse the change might also cause problems. You must either (a) perform any read-modify-write cycle in a single transaction with `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` for any reads; or (b) "touch" objects you read, so you update any optimistic lock field and the transaction that flushes changes to disk fails if there's a conflict.

Comment: @CraigRinger: Would you mind writing an example of (a) and/or (b)? I'd be happy to accept is an answer too. I think I get what you are saying, but I'm having trouble visualising the practical solution since there's so many callbacks and ways to do this.

Comment: I don't really do Rails; that's why I left a comment, not wrote an answer. But I suggest starting with http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic.html and http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Optimistic.html